# Vaadin SpringBoot Autowire a @SpringView annotated class -> instantiation of ViewCache fails

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, autowired

As topic says: shouldn't I be able to autowire a @SpringView annotaed class with vaadin and spring boot addon. I get an unsatisfied dependency exception. Adding @SpringComponent does not do the trick. Help appreciated

Edit:
I just want to Autowire a class that is annotaed @SpringView (autowireing @SpringCOmponent works apperently)
I dug deeper and found that it has Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.spring.internal.ViewCache]

Code would be:

```
@SpringView
Foo{
}
```

full Exception is:

```
Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [cuscus.client.ui.presenter.LoginPresenter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewCache' defined in com.vaadin.spring.VaadinConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.spring.internal.ViewCache]: Factory method 'viewCache' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

regards Chris

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. If you did not already have the chance, take a minute to familiarize yourself with the [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic. Afterwards, if posting a [sscce](http://sscce.org) is not possible, please share at least a description of your scenario (what you're trying to achieve), the stacktrace of your exception and the relevant code. As your question stands now, there is little information to go by...

Answer (score 1):

Usually this null pointer exception happens because the current UI instance is not initialized at the time of the bean instantiation. To solve this issue use @SpringComponent and @UIScope annotation together on views which are (for example) injected into your UI class.